# js code does not work in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

I put some js code in the application.js fileand it does not work...

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

//...

obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});

//...

$(function() {

    var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

    $(document).click(function() {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

also iI activated a line in the initializers/assets.rb file:

```
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

but anyway my code is unavailable for using in a view. I think there should be nothing extra, as it is in the application.js.

Or may be there should be something else?

Comment: On what environment you have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1) Have you mentioned this in your application layout??

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' =>  true %>
```

2) After this, use alert message in your application.js

```
alert('Hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

Working javascript that is in `applications.js` will work. So I'm guessing your problem isn't the `application.js` part of it, it's your function isn't working.

Add a `console.log 'clicked'` to your `click` function to see if fires on click. I think your javascript problem could be tied to your click function not in a [`document.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

Answer (score 0):

> Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

By looking above line of code. I guess you have `search.js` file. Whenever you want to use external js file(manually added) then you have to inform **application.js** file to include such file.

So your `application.js` file should be( If you wanted to add **`search.js`** which is not under `app/assets/javascript/` and placed under `vendor/assets/javascript/`)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require search  #js file will be added like this without it's extension 
//= require_tree .
```

**Note:** `//= require_tree` will include all js files which are under `app/assets/javascript/` folder.

Comment: If you are using //= require_tree then there is no need to mention //= require search explicitly.

Comment: @Umar : But If search.js file is under vendor folder then I think it's required

Comment: Yeah, but then don't use //= require_tree